# Get alternate lines form a text file using Apache Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a text file with more than 1000 lines of text, and I want to process alternate lines from that text file. ie, first process line 2 then line 4,line 6 like that . So how can I get these alternate lines from a text file using `Apache Pig`?

Answer (score 0):

You can pre-process the file before you copy to HDFS. Sed and AWK are great utility for such data manipulation.

```
sed -n '0~2p' 'input file name' > 'output file name'
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a Pig UDF which extends FilterFunc. Use a Counter in UDF to increment the value when each line is comming. Filter the lines which has odd counter value.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Since Pig would translate to a MapReduce job there is no guarantee that the lines from the file would be processed in a sequential order. The file would be split into different chunks and processed separately.

Comment: he has mentioned that file contains 1000 lines of txt and hence i am assuming the total size of the file to be below 64MB. Your point also makes sense.

Comment: Actually, there are some UDFs (check Enumerate from DataFu) that would do this. I'm not sure how memory intensive they would be though since a lot of aggregate functions actually pass the entire bag into the memory and might not be suitable for all purposes.